# Checking if there are no numbers from cellular services

Tags: python

I have this piece of code, which raises an exception if there are no numbers from 3 services. I really don't like how it looks at the moment.

```
no_numbers = False
if use_verizon_sms:
  if not Api.check_avalible_credits():
    no_numbers = True
elif use_verizon:
  if not buy_verizon_number():
    no_numbers = True
else:
  if not check_count_numbers():
    no_numbers = True

if no_numbers:
  raise Exception("THERE IS NO AVAILABLE NUMBERS")
```

A shorter version looks even more ugly to me and less clear:

```
if (use_verizon_sms and not Api.check_avalible_credits()) or \
  (use_verizon and not buy_verizon_number()) or \
  not check_count_numbers():
  raise Exception("THERE IS NO AVAILABLE NUMBERS")
```

Do you have any ideas how to rewrite it?

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview! It would really help if you could add a description of what this code is trying to achieve. Also you should add a more descriptive title, right now I have no idea what it is trying to say.

Comment: That code alone looks just fine, but some context might change the situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look whether you can extract the code into a function. It then may look like this.

```
def has_no_numbers():
  if use_verizon_sms:
    return Api.check_avalible_credits()

  if use_verizon:
    return buy_verizon_number()

  if check_count_numbers()
    return True

  raise Exception("THERE IS NO AVAILABLE NUMBERS")
```

Comment: I think the `raise Exception('blah')` should be replaced with `return False`.

Comment: @OskarSkog: When the code reaches the exception, it looks more like someone has forgotten to insert code for handling another "source of numbers", so the exception looks reasonable to me.

Comment: Roland, that code behaves differently to the original.  Did you mean to write, `if has_no_numbers(): raise Exception` (outside of the function)?

Comment: This solution actually throws back 3 different types of results. Boolean, API's result and an Exception.  Every time you'd use the block, you'd need to try/except trap it and try to figure out what result you got from it. Did I get a True? Did I get a False? Why is it True? Because of check_count_numbers? Did I need to buy_verizon numbers? What did my program just do? I have no idea what it did.

Answer (score 0):

I would attempt something like this (I've written this snippet so you can read it through like english to understand the change program flow which is what the question is asking; *not how I'd actually write my code*).

```
def check_for_no_numbers():
    no_numbers = check_for_numbers()

    def check_for_numbers():
        return check_count_numbers()

    if not no_numbers:
        no_numbers = check_verizon(Api, use_verizon, use_verizon_sms)

    def check_verizon(Api, use_verizon, use_verizon_sms):
        if use_verizon_sms:
            result = Api.check_available_credits()
            if not result:
                return True

        if use_verizon:
            result = buy_verizon_number()
            if not result:
                return True

        return False

    return no_numbers


some_program_logic = check_for_no_numbers()

if not some_program_logic:
    raise Exception("THERE ARE NO AVAILABLE NUMBERS")
```